# Problem with JSON-RPC request using jsonrpcclient - Python

Tags: python, json, request

So I was trying to use the API at random.org and I have the following code:

```
from jsonrpcclient import request
import requests

reply = requests.post("https://api.random.org/json-rpc/4/invoke", params = {"method": "generateIntegerSequences",
                                                                            "apiKey": "[key]",
                                                                            "n": 1,
                                                                            "length": 100,
                                                                            "min": 1,
                                                                            "max": 1000})

print(reply)
```

When I run it I get:

```
<Response [415]>
```

What is the error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure about the key?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, I just removed it from the above code

Answer (score 0):

You get a 415 status code because you are not passing a body to a post request:

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code
> indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the
> payload format is in an unsupported format.

In your case you are using `requests.post` with the right parameters. You need to use the `json` parameter instead of `params` to pass a json body to a post request:

```py
requests.post("https://api.random.org/json-rpc/4/invoke", json={"method": "generateIntegerSequences", ...})

Out: <Response [200]>
```